# ForActionsMatching an area and controller name?

Tags: fluent-security

Is there a way to build a predicate down to a list of actions with a specific name, in a specific controller, in a specific area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're area controllers are in a namespace specific to that area, you should be able to use the following:

```
configuration.ForActionsMatching(info =>
   info.ControllerType.Namespace.StartsWith("Some.Namespace")
)
```

https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity/wiki/Securing-controllers

If you're areas are in an assembly not reference by the application running FluentSecurity, you should have a look at Profiles in FluentSecurity 2.0.

https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity/wiki/Profiles

Comment: Ahh, I didn't think about querying based on the namespace. I think I can make that work. Thanks!